# Summation and sorting of unique values using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file like:

```
A 444
C 333
D 100
B 888
D 200
D 300
A 777
A 1337
B 555
C 666
```

I need to count a sum from the second column for every unique name from the first column using awk.
I used:

`cat ./access3.log | gawk '{{a[$1]+=$2}; for (i in a) print i " - " a[i]}' | sort | sort -rn | head -3`

I intended  to get

```
A 2558
B 1443
C 999
```

Instead I get

```
D - 600
D - 600
D - 600
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: you have to move the for loop into `END` block.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
sort inputfile | awk '{seen[$1]+=$2}END{for (i in seen) print i, seen[i]}'
```

output:

```
A 2558
B 1443
C 999
D 600
```

---

As karakfa mentioned, changing the order of `awk` and `sort` is more efficient:

```
awk '{seen[$1]+=$2}END{for (i in seen) print i, seen[i]}'  inputfile | sort
```

Comment: doesn't really matter here, but if you sort after summation it will have less work to do and will be faster for large data sets (>10^6).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative - single GNU **`datamash`** command:

```
datamash -sW -g1 sum 2 < access3.log
```

The output:

```
A   2558
B   1443
C   999
D   600
```

Comment: I wish I had excuses to use datamash more often.  It's so great.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk and [controlling array scanning order](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html#Controlling-Scanning) to sort the output:

```
$ awk ' {
    a[$1]+=$2                              # sum and hash to a
} 
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"  # order is greatest value first
    for(i in a) {                          
        print i, a[i]
        if(++c==3)                         # exit after first three values
            exit
    }
}' file
A 2558
B 1443
C 999
```